# Is there a way for the contract to test what cluster (mainnet, devnet, testnet) it is on?

Tags: devnet, mainnet, deploy, local-cluster

In my project, I have some code that is unable to run on testnet, so I want to just pass sample data there.  I'm wondering if it's possible to detect the environment so that I do not have to run different contracts for each environment.

Comment: are you trying to deploy a program in some other cluster than before? `solana config set --url localhost` (can substitute localhost for devnet etc), and `solana config get` returns your RPC url

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to pre-load an account with configuration data on each of the clusters which just has the name of the cluster in the account data field.  Then your program can check that address to make a decision about how to proceed.

When you run your program, you'll still need to include the address of that "config"/"environment" account with each instruction so your program can read from it. As long as you use the same address on all clusters I think it would work.

From a security standpoint, your program obviously shouldn't assume whatever address it receives as configuration/environment is trustworthy.

For a simpler solution, you could also consider just sending in the behaviour you want as part of the instruction call.

Comment: That's pretty clever.  I'll probably end up just doing it the slow, manual way to avoid the potential security risk, but this is probably the best way

Comment: Thanks @web3man. If you think it might speed up your workflow I think the on-chain program can just compare the passed-in "config" address with the _expected_ "config" address (like hard-code it in the program). If they match, the program should be able to trust the data it finds there assuming you control the private key. Bonus: if they don't match, the program can refuse to do the "wrong" thing for the environment and just error out.